# is this secure: email account that can only be accessed by sending and receiving emails within gmail

Tags: email, spoofing, gmail, service-account

i am creating a game of sorts where you use and earn credits to accomplish tasks. I am curious if you can effectively use gmail's security features to secure these submissions if the emails are all in one of the major "safe" ESPs - that use SPF and DMARC.

For simplicity let's just say every account except the game_host@myserver is a gmail email account.
https://support.google.com/a/topic/4388154?hl=en&ref_topic=29818

you obviously know it is coming from gmail and thereby has to be the correct sender/receiver.  no spoofing possible and the whole message should stay https the whole time right?
https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en

Comment: Did you consider to have your players sign their emails with [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy)? Not very comfortable, but still better than forcing them to use a specific email provider.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail's spam filter is only concerned with **spam**.  Gmail will deliver email with SPF failures, and an invalid or missing DKIM signature.   If you don't believe me, [send a spoofed email to your self](http://www.anonymailer.net/).

If you are concerned with spoofed email,  then it would be better to use a service such like the [Sendgrid inbound parse webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html),  which will include detailed SPF and DMARC information for all incoming email.

Comment: Absolutely true.  I just tried this myself, and Rook is correct.  Gmail will most certainly deliver email (into the spam folder) with a clearly faked  gmail from address.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem with gmail, even though better with SSL, is that you cannot be sure of the sender. Anyone can make a gmail account -- effectively anonymously, so unless you know the person and were given the email address by that person, you cannot be sure who it was who created it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - that's correct. However, if i provided a code to users through another medium, or i simply don't care to restrain anyone from talking to my mail@servers.  right?

Comment: That sounds like a good direction.